# ASTContext::getParents() - Ancestors or Parents?

Tags: llvm-clang

`ASTContext::getParents` is supposed to return the parents of a given node. My question is how can one AST node have more than one parent??
I suspected that the doc might mean the member function returns the ancestors of a given node, not just the parents and i tested it. size`returns a size of`1` and all the nodes i tested only have one parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a couple of years but anyways.
I did ask the question on the clang mailing list but the archive link doesn't seem to exist anymore.
The `parents` member function could be `parent` when it comes to C since in C, AST nodes can't have more than one parent. `parents` makes sense in C++ where nodes can have more than one parent in the AST. This happens for example with template instantiations and lambdas where a node can end up with more than one parent.